# Cannot instantiate the type MenuItem

Tags: java, android, instantiation

I have a class MenuItem, and a class ContentResolverMenuItem which grabs data from my SQLite database and inserts it into a local MenuItem object.  They were working fine until the MenuItem class got deleted somehow.  I rewrote the class, and now in ContentResolverMenuItem I'm getting an error when trying to instantiate an instance of MenuItem.

MenuItem:

```
public class MenuItem {

int menuItemId;
int subcategoryId;
String name;
String description;
String picturePath;
double price;

public MenuItem(){};

public MenuItem(int menuItemId, int subcategoryId, String name,
        String description, String picturePath, double price) {
    this.menuItemId = menuItemId;
    this.subcategoryId = subcategoryId;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.picturePath = picturePath;
    this.price = price;
}
public int getMenuItemId() {
    return menuItemId;
}
public void setMenuItemId(int menuItemId) {
    this.menuItemId = menuItemId;
}
public int getSubcategoryId() {
    return subcategoryId;
}
public void setSubcategoryId(int subcategoryId) {
    this.subcategoryId = subcategoryId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getPicturePath() {
    return picturePath;
}
public void setPicturePath(String picturePath) {
    this.picturePath = picturePath;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
}
```

ContentResolverMenuItem:

```
public class ContentResolverMenuItem 
{
    Context context;    
    ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItems = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    private static ContentResolverMenuItem ref;

private ContentResolverMenuItem(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    String[] projection = new String[]{TabletContentProvider.KEY_ID, 
                                       TabletContentProvider.KEY_SUBCATEGORY_ID,
                                       TabletContentProvider.KEY_NAME,
                                       TabletContentProvider.KEY_DESCRIPTION,
                                       TabletContentProvider.KEY_PICTURE_PATH,
                                       TabletContentProvider.KEY_PRICE};
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(TabletContentProvider.MENU_ITEM_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    menuItems.clear();
    // use cursor to insert rows from table into ArrayList
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do 
        {
            int menuItemId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TabletContentProvider.KEY_ID));
            int subcategoryId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TabletContentProvider.KEY_SUBCATEGORY_ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TabletContentProvider.KEY_NAME));
            String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TabletContentProvider.KEY_DESCRIPTION));
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TabletContentProvider.KEY_PICTURE_PATH));
            double price = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(TabletContentProvider.KEY_PRICE));
              // ERROR IS HERE
            menuItems.add(new MenuItem (menuItemId, subcategoryId, name, description, picturePath, price));
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    android.util.Log.v("CRMenuItem", "menuItem data processed");
}
...
...
```

I didn't change a thing at all, and now this is happening and I have no idea why.  I have an identical set of classes for another table in the database and they work fine.

Comment: Are you sure you're not importing `android.view.MenuItem` in `ContentResolverMenuItem`?

Comment: check your imports, MenuItem is a class that exists in Android framework. Also, change the name of that class

Comment: android.view.MenuItem was imported in ContentResolverMenuItem.  I deleted that line and now it's working.  So I should change the class name even though it works now?